# 'Cannot find module error' after I use babel to convert my JS code.(still got a problem even after files are converted well)

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

So I tried using Babel to convert my code so that I can run this by node. **package.json** build is this,

```
"build": "babel ./public/src -d ./public/lib -w"
```

When I do `npm run build`

```
PS C:\users\leepc\babel\public> npm run build

> babel@1.0.0 build C:\users\leepc\babel
> babel ./public/src -d ./public/lib -w

public\src\blogpost.js -> public\lib\blogpost.js
public\src\main.js -> public\lib\main.js
public\src\publication.js -> public\lib\publication.js
```

It works right and shows me exactly what I want.
My **.babelrc** preset is **es2015**
I run my **main.js** code and this is happened.

```
PS C:\users\leepc\babel\public\lib> node main.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984
  throw err;
  ^
    at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27) 
    at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)       
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\users\leepc\babel\public\lib\main.js:3:17)       
    at Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)      17)       
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:     
10)                                                                            
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)                    
    at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)           
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_m     
ain.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 
'C:\\users\\leepc\\babel\\public\\lib\\main.js' ]  
}
```

[This is files and folders list in img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F053.png)

My codes are coverted well, but it still got some Module problems. How can I solve this issue? Sorry this is my first time posting question in this website, if I missed some information pls tell me.

edit:

Here is ***.babelrc***

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }
```

Comment: can you post your .babelrc file?

Comment: okay. I edited my post and the last one is ***.babelrc*** code.

Comment: try using the _env_ preset targeting _node_, as explained here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-env

Comment: Hmm sadly it does not work. Maybe I should check my codes again.

Comment: oh nvm, it turns out, I should put a plugin..haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turns out, I should combine both of answers above.

First, I have to check whether my import plugin is right or wrong. So I just re-installed it.

```
npm install babel-plugin-import --save-dev
```

Make sure not to forget put plugin opitions. In my cases, I use this in .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": [["import", { "libraryName": "antd" }]]
}
```

this `"plugins": [["import", { "libraryName": "antd" }]` line means import js modulary.

And also next stuff, I have to make import path to be corrected.

```
import { create as newBlogPost } from "blogpost.js";
```

change this to

```
import { create as newBlogPost } from "./blogpost.js";
```

By doing this, now I can get a result that I wanted so far.

```
PS C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\lib> node main.js

    Title: For and against let 
    By: Kyle Simpson 
    October 27, 2014
```

So majorly, 1. Check whether I missed some plugins or packages ( in my cases, I forgot import package ) 2. Make sure to check your import path

Thank you for help guys.